# I need a text field or "Label vs TextField"

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I develop a game with cocos2d-x rc1 and I need a text field where I will show the score of the player. Which one to use `cocos2d::Label` or `TextField` defined in cocos/ui/UITextField.cpp ? What is the difference? For example, I have noticed that `Label` has `enableShadow`, but `TextField` misses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use a `TextField` for a mere output field. (Jeff Johnson: "GUI Bloopers", Blooper #17.)

Text fields are meant for input. The fact that they can be active or passive doesn't mean that they should be used in always-passive mode for output. To display a result, use a `Label` indicating what the following value is, and another `Label` for the value itself.

```
Score:  42
```

**Later**
One reason is that an inactive `TextField` typically has an appearance that dampens its visibility, like being grayed out. Another one is that the border surrounding a `TextField` identifies it as a place where data can be entered, if not now, then some other time; and this is bound to irritate users that are trained to observe such niceties - and there *are*, me 4 1 ;-)

Comment: Good point, so they are different in a way that one is for displaying a text, and another one is and interactive input field. But why not have ReadOnly option for TextField and remove Label at all?

Comment: See the added rationale. JJ is quite explicit: *never*!

Comment: Just in ActionScript3 TextField is for both cases. I don't insist that it is good, but it works many years. Unfortunately I could not find "Jeff Johnson: "GUI Bloopers", Blooper #17". Is there a link?

Comment: A physical copy is all I have :-) -- All of the bloopers in the book have been "working for years". -- Actually, JJ concedes that you *might* use a `TextField` for display, provided you can tweak its appearance to be an exact lookalike for `Label`, but, as he writes, "such toolkits are rare to nonexistent".